# run two python files in parallel from terminal

Tags: python, multithreading

If I have two python programs called *test1.py* and *test2.py*, How can I run them in parallel in terminal?
Does

```html
python test1.py|python test2.py
```

do that?

Comment: That does run both scripts in parallel. It also attaches the `stdout` of the first process to the `stdin` of the second process. I'm not sure whether you want that part, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will pipe the output from test1.py into test2.py.

If you simply want to run both in parallel then use this instead:

`python test1.py &; python test2.py &`

The `&` will fork the command into its own process.

Comment: I upvoted because I think this is what OP wants... but piping does run them both in parallel - and binds stdout/stdin.

Comment: Good point. I am making the assumption that he simply wants both to run and that piping the output isn't desired.